# Escaped JSON response with [WebMethod]

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, asmx

The JSON response from the following code is wrongly escaped as described below.

My webmethod is like this:

```
    [WebMethod (Description="doc here")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public string responseMyObject() {
            if (!Setup()) return "";

            ...
            Proxy pu = new Proxy(...);
...

            string toReturn = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(pu.getMyObject());
            Console.WriteLine(toReturn);
            return toReturn;
    }
```

from the console I get:

```
{"field1":vaule1,"field2":value2}
```

from JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myapi/myClass.asmx/responseMyObject",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
                    var object = msg.d;
                    alert(object.field1);
    }
});
```

The problem is that in the HTTP response header I can see that the JSON response is wrongly (?) escaped in the following way:

```
{"d":"{\"field1\":value1,\"field2\":value2}"}
```

What's strange is that the console print is fine (but not yet encapsulated in {d: ...}

```
{"field1":value1,"field2":value2}
```

With similar code, if I call a [WebMethod] that returns basic types (no object) the JSON response is ok. Like:

{"d":8080}

Comment: The JSON is not wrong, it is escaped correctly

Comment: it's taken your JSON ( String ) and wrapped it into a JSON object wrapper

Comment: Can you give us any more details on the type being returned by getMyObject()? It might highlight the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: click on the magnifying glass in the debug console; select "text previewer": it's all fine, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : WebService
{    

  [WebMethod (Description="doc here")]    
  [ScriptMethod( UseHttpGet=false, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]     
  public MyObjectType responseMyObject() 
  {
      Proxy pu = new Proxy(...);

      return pu.GetMyObject();
  }

}
```

You dont need a JSON serializer, tagging it with the ScriptService attribute gives it tie ability to serialize JSON out. You were pre serializing the JSON and then serializing it again :(

Comment: Now the response is an empty {}

Comment: your object actually have properties? And have installed the System.Web.Extensions ? 3.5 sp1 adds alot of stuff

Comment: your names field1, leads me to believe they are fields, change to Property and give it a go

Answer (score 3):

Why are you calling JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject?

Can't you just change the return type of your method to be the type returned by pu.getMyObject() and the framework will do the rest?

In other words...

```
[WebMethod (Description="doc here")]    
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]     
public MyObjectType responseMyObject() 
{
    Proxy pu = new Proxy(...);

    ...

    return pu.GetMyObject();
}
```

At the moment I think you're serializing your object into a JSON format and then, when you return from the method, the framework is serializing that string (which contains JSON formatted data) into a JSON format.

Comment: Now the response is an empty {}