# Consuming .NET web services with complex types in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, service

Can i consume .NET web service and use it complex types in PHP?

Example:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetData()
{
     return new DataSet();
}
```

Can i consume this method and use DataSet class methods in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely. .NET web services return serialized representations of .NET objects - and you can't use .NET objects in PHP because that's just not how it works.

You'd be better off exposing each of the methods you need as a separate web service call that just returns data, configure .NET to serialize the data as XML or JSON, and then use a PHP library to deserialize the results into a format your PHP code can work with.

Comment: how to configure .NET to serialize data as JSON?

Comment: See examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811353/escaped-json-response-with-webmethod