# javascriptserilizer not serializing properly

Tags: web-services, javascriptserializer

i have a webservice whih has only one method in it

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string GetMovies()
        {
            using (var dataContext = new MovieCollectionDataContext())
            {
                var query = dataContext.Movies.Select(m =>new{m.Title,m.ReleaseDate}).Take(20);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return serializer.Serialize(query);
            }
        }
```

it serilize the object but when i get the result in firebug it look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"Title":"SQL","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"},{"Title":"Termonator Salvation","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"}]</string>
```

iam using Kendo and my jquery method is

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/MovieService.asmx/GetMovies"
                            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                        }
                    },
                    change: function (e) {
                        alert(e);

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e[2]);
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    schema: {
                        data: "d"

                    }
```

in the above jquery there is an error even when it calls i got this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

please help me to get the proper JSON plz i really neeed proper JSON to do my work

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to parse?  The whole response won't parse because it's XML, not json.  If you are trying to parse just the value of the string element then you probably need to wrap it in quotes.

Update:

`JSON.parse('[{"Title":"SQL","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"},{"Title":"Termonator Salvation","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"}]')`

Comment: see my edit questions that what actually i am trying to do may be you understand what i am trying to convey

Comment: ya. your data type you are getting back is not json though. that's xml.  you need to configure your service to return json.

Comment: somethign like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228648/webmethod-returning-json-but-the-response-obj-in-my-ajax-callback-is-only-a

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811353/escaped-json-response-with-webmethod

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows how to return JSON from an ASMX service: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

And here is a running project showing how to bind a Kendo Grid to an ASMX service: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-web-service-crud